# Linux - Save only recent 10 folders and delete the rest

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder that contains versions of my application, each time I upload a new version a new sub-folder is created for it, the sub-folder name is the current timestamp, here is a printout of the main folder used (ls -l |grep ^d):

```
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-03-31 16:18 20110331161649
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-03-31 16:21 20110331161914
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-03-31 16:53 20110331165035
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-03-31 16:59 20110331165712
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-03 20:18 20110403201607
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-03 20:38 20110403203613
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-04 14:39 20110405143725
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-06 15:24 20110406151805
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-06 15:36 20110406153157
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-06 16:02 20110406155913
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-10 21:10 20110410210928
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-10 21:50 20110410214939
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-10 22:15 20110410221414
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-04-11 22:19 20110411221810
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-01 21:30 20110501212953
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-01 23:02 20110501230121
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-03 21:57 20110503215252
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-06 16:17 20110506161546
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-11 10:00 20110511095709
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-11 10:13 20110511100938
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-12 14:34 20110512143143
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-13 22:13 20110513220824
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-14 22:26 20110514222548
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-05-14 23:03 20110514230258
```

I'm looking for a command that will leave the last 10 versions (sub-folders) and deletes the rest.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There you go. **(edited)**

`ls -dt */ | tail -n +11 | xargs rm -rf`

First list directories recently modified then take all of them except first 10, then send them to `rm -rf`.

Comment: im getting: rm: cannot remove directory: `.'

Comment: Whoa! First, `ls -dt` only ever outputs `.`. Second, if you correct that to `ls -t`, you are deleting the 10 newest files, exactly the opposite of what was asked. Third, if there are files other than the directories considered, your script will happily delete random stuff. Fourth, if there are “strange” file names, your script could do anything, because you're parsing the output of `ls`, [not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and you're passing unprepared input to [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).

Comment: wait a sec I have noticed that you want to leave first 10 and remove all others, I thought that you need to remove first 10. hmm your error is interesting.

Comment: i want to keep the latest 10.

Comment: Fixed. Grep and sed will slow down, `ls -d` will be faster. (when compared to other solutions). And `tail +10` will delete 10th record, too. therefore `tail +11` is better.

Comment: almost, now im getting: tail: cannot open `+11' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: I think our `tail` versions are different. I'm on Mac, wait i'll check on Linux.

Comment: @Ran: That should be `tail -n +11` (`tail +11` is an obsolete form). But as you might guess, I don't recommend this, see my comment above regarding the use of `ls` and `xargs`.

Comment: Yes, in linux it will be `tail -n +11`

Comment: @Gilles: so is there any other solution instead of ls and xargs?

Comment: If you don't have weird (and dangerous) folder names (it seems you only have numbers here), then you do not need such security. In addition, this will operate faster on filesystem since it request directory listing only once.

Comment: @Ran: If you can guarantee that all the directories are these YYYYMMDDHHMMSS directories, then ahmet's answer is now correct. Note however that it relies on the directories' modification times, not the names, which is rather fragile. I still recommend the solution in my answer.

Comment: this does not only select directories, but also any files in the current directory!

Comment: @Tilo: No, that's ok, `*/` only matches directories, not other files.

Comment: If you just want to sort by filename (not the actual date of the folder) you can use this: `ls -dr */ | tail +11 | xargs rm -rf`

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -dt1 /path/to/folder/*/ | sed '11,$p' | rm -r
```

this assumes those are the only directories and no others are present in the working directory.

- `ls -dt1` will normally only print the newest directory however the `/*/` will
  only match directories and print their full paths the `1` ensures one
  line per match/listing `t` sorts time with newest at the top.
- `sed` takes the 11th line on down to the bottom and prints only those lines, which are then passed to `rm`.

You can use xargs, but for testing you may wish to remove `| rm -r` to see if the directories are listed properly first.

Answer (score 2):

If the directories' names contain the date one can delete all but the last 10 directories with the default alphabetical sort

```
ls -d */ | head -n -10  | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -lt | grep ^d | sed -e '1,10d' |  awk '{sub(/.* /, ""); print }' | xargs rm -rf
```

Explanation:

- list all contents of current directory in chronological order (most recent files first)
- filter out all the directories
- ignore the 10 first lines / directories
- use awk to extract the file names from the remaining 'ls -l' output
- remove the files

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name \\.| sort | tac | sed -e '1,10d' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: i think it should be: ls -l| grep ^d | tac | sed -e '1,10d' | xargs rm -rf

Comment: You're parsing the output of `ls`, [not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and you're passing unprepared input to [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). Your `grep ^d` isn't doing what you think it's doing — if you had `ls -l`, you'd need to extract file names (not a good idea), but since you don't, there's no directory indicator.

Comment: yeah, that was junk.  my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following sequence. I use a [similar approach](https://superuser.com/a/1670669/1495862) on my Synology NAS to delete old backups. It doesn't rely on the folder names, instead it uses the last modified time to decide which folders to delete. It also uses zero-termination in order to correctly handle quotes, spaces and newline characters in the folder names:

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%Ts\t' -print0 \
| sort -rnz \
| tail -n +11 -z \
| cut -f2- -z \
| xargs -0 -r rm -rf
```

**IMPORTANT**: This will delete any matching folders! I strongly recommend doing a test run first by replacing the last command `xargs -0 -r rm -rf` with `xargs -0` which will echo the matching folders instead of deleting them.

A short explanation of each step:

1. `find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%Ts\t' -print0`
   [Find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) all directories (`-type d`) directly inside the backup folder (`-maxdepth 1`) except the backup folder itself (`-mindepth 1`), print (`-printf`) the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (`%Ts`) of the last modification followed by a tab character (`\t`, used in step 4) and the full file name followed by a null character (`-print0`).
2. `sort -rnz`
   [Sort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) the zero-terminated items (`-z`) from the previous step using a numerical comparison (`-n`) and reverse the order (`-r`). The result is a list of all folders sorted by their last modification time in descending order.
3. `tail -n +11 -z`
   Print the last lines ([`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)) from the previous step starting from line 11 (`-n +11`) considering each line as zero-terminated (`-z`). This excludes the newest 10 folders (by modification time) from the remaining steps.
4. `cut -f2- -z`
   [Cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) each line from the second field until the end (`-f2-`) treating each line as zero-terminaded (`-z`) to obtain a list containing the full path to each folder older than 10 days.
5. `xargs -r -0 rm -rf`
   Take the  zero-terminated (`-0`) items from the previous step ([`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)), and, if there are any (`-r` avoids running the command passed to xargs if there are no nonblank characters), force delete (`rm -rf`) them.

Answer (score -2):

Your directory names are sorted in chronological order, which makes this easy. The list of directories in chronological order is just `*`, or `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` to be more precise. So you want to delete all but the last 10 of them.

```
set [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
while [ $# -gt 10 ]; do
  rm -rf "$1"
  shift
fi
```

(While there are more than 10 directories left, delete the oldest one.)